# I want to override the buttons.phtml in my module

Tags: magento2

I want to override the **buttons.phtml** file in my module can anyone help me out

please. For more info, please find the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please write more description about your question

Comment: can you please take a look at screenshot @Ronak Chauhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow below steps:

**Step:1** 
First copy base file `buttons.phtml` at location `vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\info\buttons.phtml` to your current theme for eg. `app\design\frontend\{Your_theme_name}\default\Magento_Sales\templates\order\info\buttons.phtml`

**Step:2** After change code in your theme file (`app\design\frontend\{Your_theme_name}\default\Magento_Sales\templates\order\info\buttons.phtml`)

**Setp:3** Run Compiler command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and check your changes

**Second method:**

> **Setp:1**

Create Buttons.php file (`app\code\{Your-Vendor-name}\{Your-Module-Name}\Block\Order\Info\Buttons`)

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Block of links in Order view page
 */
namespace {Your-Vendor-name}\{Your-Module-Name}\Block\Order\Info;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;

class Buttons extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = '{Your-Vendor-name}\{Your-Module-Name}::order/info/buttons.phtml';

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
    }

    /**
     * Get url for printing order
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrintUrl($order)
    {
        if (!$this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)) {
            return $this->getUrl('sales/guest/print', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
        }
        return $this->getUrl('sales/order/print', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
    }

    /**
     * Get url for reorder action
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReorderUrl($order)
    {
        if (!$this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)) {
            return $this->getUrl('sales/guest/reorder', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
        }
        return $this->getUrl('sales/order/reorder', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
    }
}
```

> Setp:2

Create `buttons.phtml` file (`app\code\{Your-Vendor-name}\{Your-Module-Name}\view\frontend\templates\order\info\buttons.phtml`)

```
<div class="actions">
    <?php  $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder')->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
        <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo
        $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
            ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
        ?>' class="action order">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Reorder1') ?></span>
        </a>
    <?php endif ?>
    <a class="action print"
       href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPrintUrl($_order) ?>"
       onclick="this.target='_blank';">
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Print Order2') ?></span>
    </a>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

> Setp:3
>   Create `di.xml` file (`app\code\{Your-Vendor-name}\{Your-Module-Name}\etc\di.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons" type="{Your-Vendor-name}\{Your-Module-Name}\Block\Order\Info\Buttons" />
</config>
```

> Setp:4

Run commands `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` & `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and check your changes

Comment: if i direct copy the same location in my app/code/Mymodule will it works @Abdul

Comment: @Pranay K It is not work. Please check my updates (Secomd method)

Comment: Can it be possible to override every template files like this with corresponding block @Abdul

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 1):

You can override buttons.phtml by override the `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons.php` class

`di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons" type="<Vendor>\<Module>\Block\Order\Info\Buttons"/>
</config>
```

`<Vendor>\<Modulename>\Block\Order\Info\Buttons.php`

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor>\<ModuleName>\Block\Order\Info;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;

class Buttons extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = '<Vendor_ModuleName>::order/info/buttons.phtml';
}
```

Now you can place you custom buttons.phtml in your module as per path `view/frontend/order/info/buttons.phtml`

Feel free to contact!

Comment: Can it be possible to override every template files like this with corresponding block @Ronak Cahuhan

Comment: Yes, You can override each template but some templates called directly from class also so you need to manage it. else  by using layout you can override templates

Comment: i tried to override list template but it is not overridding the above way.can you just give me clarity.on these. @Ronak Chauhan

Comment: you can use layout override and give your custom path to it

Comment: <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"><Vendor_ModuleName>::catalog/product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: If my solution help you correct way then you can mark it correct so it may help others too

Answer (score 1):

Use sequence in your **module.xml** in order to load phtml file from your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.title">
            <container name="order.actions.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="actions-toolbar order-actions-toolbar">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons" as="buttons" name="sales.order.info.buttons" cacheable="false" template="Vendor_Module::order/info/buttons.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now copy **buttons.phtml** from

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/info/buttons.phtml

and paste into

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/order/info/buttons.phtml